# Google Chrome Version 33.0.1750.117 is loading the css properly only on refreshing the page.?

Tags: css, google-chrome, loading, page-refresh

Google Chrome Version 33.0.1750.117 is loading the css properly only on refreshing the page. some of the text are not displayed on intial loading of the page, which is displayed only after refresh???? while the site is working fine with ie and firefox, please advise a solution as i am not technical.

Comment: Do you mean that the page on initial view is broken, and when you refresh the page fixes itself?

Comment: yes .....primarily the issue with text......as the pictures are displaying properly